# Count how many times an IP number appears in a text file - C Program

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, fgets, strncmp

I have a log file of 10 hits e.g. one line is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2007:13:55:36 ­0700]"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0" 200 2326 "http://www.example.com/links.html" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
```

The format of each line is the same i.e. the IP address is always at the start.

I've currently read in the file using fopen and fgets but now I want to count how many unique IPs there are in the file, as well as count how many times an IP 'hits'. Not sure how I would attempt this.. Any tips on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: It depends if the file format is fixed and ou know where to look for the IP addresses or if you need to scan the lines for patterns that *look* like IP addresses.   This would be approximate since URLs may contain such patterns producing false positives.

Comment: If the  IP address is always at the beginning, it is relatively easy to parse them with `sscanf` after checking for proper format.

Comment: " e.g. **one** line is:" **4** lines of data?

Comment: @chux Sorry, that's the way it copied in. All the data is supposed to be on one line

Comment: @chqrlie The IP is always at the start so I will have a look into sscanf, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Code can march though the file looking for the ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd pattern.

Avoided use `"%d"` or `"%u"` as they accept leading spaces, and `'-'` and `'+'`.

Pseudo code

```
Read from a file until EOF found
  repeatedly look for a digit
  if it is found
    note position
    put digit back into stream
    look for ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd
    if found
      decode (and test for values > 255)
      if successful return result
    go back to position

return fail value;
```

Sample code.  Should also have IO error checking.

```
unsigned long Parse_IP(FILE *inf) {
  int ch;
  for ((ch = fgetc(inf)) != EOF) {
    if (isdigit(ch)) {
      long pos = ftell(inf);
      ungetc(ch, inf);
      char buf[4][4];
      int count = fscanf(inf, "%3[0-9].%3[0-9].%3[0-9].%3[0-9]", 
          buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);
      if (count == 4) {
        unsigned long ip = 0;  
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
          int digit = atoi(buf[i]);
          if (digit > 255) break;
          ip = ip*256 + digit;
        }
        if (i == 4) return ip;  
      }
      fseek(inf, pos, SEEK_SET);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sample usage

```
unsigned long ip;
while ((ip = Parse_IP(inf)) != 0) {
  printf("ip %08lX\n", ip);
}
```

Comment: Your code may fail for pipe or console input as you assume you can `fseek` backwards, and it will mistakenly match IP addresses for these patterns: `9127.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.2550` etc.

Comment: I'm being picky, but why not accept `0.0.0.0` as a valid IP address pattern?

Comment: @chqrlie The method posted returns a 32+ bit integer using _some_ value as a failure indication.  Code may easily be amended to return an `long long` with -1 as the bad boy or save the IP address in a passed pointer location and return a `int` or 0 or 1.  `0` seemed a natural choice for "invalid value".  No compelling reason for `0`

Comment: Vintage @chux - logical, well validated, and to the point! (all clear this time `:)`